# Setup varnish just for subdomain?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Can I setup Varnish for one Subdomain and block it for all other Domains on my server?

Will this code work?

```
    backend magento244.example.com {
    .host = "magento244.example.com";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
    .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

if (req.http.host == 'www.example.com') {
    return (pass);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will bypass the cache for `www.example.com` requests.

Assuming you only want traffic to be handled for `www.example.com` and you want to block all other traffic, I'd use the following VCL code:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    // Block requests for other hosts
    if(req.http.Host != "www.example.com") {
        return(synth(403));
    }
    // The rest of your VCL code can go here
}
```

This code will return a `403 Forbidden` status for all requests that are not for the `www.example.com` host.

> If you have a different interpretation of *blocking requests*, please update your question and provide more context.